# Как в UMI CMS вывести значение поля с типом составное в yml?

Tags: xslt, umi

В UMI CMS пытаюсь вывести значение поля с типом составное в yml, перепробовал уже всё, поле выводится пустое. Ну то есть:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//property[@name = 'color']/value"/>
```

Выводится просто слово "Цвет". При этом поле с типом "выпадающий список" выводится без проблем, например:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//property[@name = 'color']/value/item/@name" />
```

Нужно получить не имя поля составное, а именно доступные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите: ["Отображение третьего столбца для поля типа Составное"](http://wiki.umisoft.ru/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5), должно стать понятно как работать с поле данного типа.